# Unable to upload files to Node.js, Express backend using Multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, express, multer

My application is running fine in my local windows environment; I am using multer to upload 2 image files from my React front-end to my Node.js & express back-end.

I set up my back-end on a personal linux server, so that my team could use it too, and I am using SSH tunneling to communicate with my back-end, however, my images are failing to upload.
Multer does not give any errors, but the file uploading appears to stop working after the first image.

Front-end code:

```
<form action='/upload' method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" style={styles} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const data = new FormData(event.target);
console.log("Posting data...");
setLoading(true);
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data)
```

Back-end code:

```
// Set multerStorage options
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const dist = path.join(__dirname, "public", "images", "scannedCards/");
        cb(null, dist);
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log("File original name: ", file.originalname);
        console.log(req.headers);
        let filename = file.originalname.split('.')[0]
        filename = filename + ".png";
        console.log("File name: ", filename);
        cb(null, `${filename}`);
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage: multerStorage});


// Post request to /upload to handle detection of cards
router.post('/', upload.array('scan', 2), async (req, res) => {.....}
```

The `console.log("File name: ", filename)` runs for the first file, but never shows up for the second one.

What could possibly be the reason for this? Could this have anything to do with CORS? Is it because I am SSH Tunneling? The rest of the application is working fine. It is just the uploading file part that is messing up!

Answer (score 1):

So, when you upload in the web form with the console open, do you see a CORS error? Do you see a network error?

I'd suggest starting with checking to see that the front end is submitting the data you expect in the network tab for both files. It could just be that there's an error in your front end on the second run.

Also, if you're able to see the first file on your sever, it's probably not a CORS issue.

I'd also suggest debugging your node server and stepping through your handling of the requests to see exactly where the break is happening. You can use chrome to debug your node server using the same chrome dev tools that you use to debug front end javascript: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into debugging the node server using dev tools. The eventual error that I get is: 
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)

Comment: Also, the data being sent from front-end is fine! It's given no problems throughout the development process.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like *something* is going wonky, but I'd need more details about what the network error actually is, or what's throwing that error. I think if you step through with a debugger, you'll be able to see where something goes wrong on the api side. XMLHttpRequest.handleError sounds like the front end error upon receiving an error from your node server. What do the request and response headers look like on the http request? You can look at the detailed request headers in the network tab of the chrome debugger.

Comment: Okay, I just checked and my uploader seems to be working fine for small sized image files but it's the large files (~110mb png files) that are the problem. I think Multer is just taking a **really** long time to upload and it times out, so this is probably a Multer specific issue. Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

Comment: oh those are massive uploads. yeah. that explains a lot. multer sticks the file in server memory, which works for small files, but that won't work for those honking beasts you're uploading. You need to use a streaming technique instead. multer 2.0 has support for the stream api, but it's still in alpha.